# Using NetGuard, what app(s)/service(s) can be restricted to prevent system updates?

Tags: ota-update, firewall, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I've been using NetGuard for a little while now, and I've really liked it so far. I hate the forced system updates which seem to come more and more frequently. For a handful of reasons, I'd like to prevent this from happening via NetGuard, if possible. I have to imagine there's a service or two which compares my Android version with the latest available version, and perhaps another which actually downloads the latest version. The problem is that the list of apps and services to restrict are vast, and I have no idea what most of them do. What on this list needs to be restricted in order to prevent all future forced updates?

Comment: Check the network usage statistics the next time when there is a new notification of an update. If you see an unexpected service with a download usage of 50-300MB (to my experience a typical size of a pure security update) then you have a candidate. If you don't  want to be forced to install system updates check [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/231289/2241). Not sure if this is also applicable for your device.

Comment: Thanks @Robert, the only thing sticking out with data usage is "System update", which I've already had restricted for a while. I've also had that setting in developer mode toggled off for some time. I've received multiple updates since. I was looking for a temporary fix until I decide to root my device, but I guess I'll be doing that sooner than I had planned. Thank you!